# VSS connection throwind error 'The request body must be empty if queueing a build with sourceBuildId.' When starting pipeline

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, tfs

I'm trying to start a pipeline using a VSS connection to azure DevOps.  When I try to queue a run with a source ID, I get the error

> The request body must be empty if queueing a build with sourceBuildId.

Here is the code that causes the error.

```cs
VssConnection connection = Connection;

ProjectHttpClient projectClient = connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
Task<TeamProject> projectTask = projectClient.GetProject("ProjectName");

BuildHttpClient buildClient = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
Task<BuildDefinition> definitionTask = buildClient.GetDefinitionAsync("ProjectName", pipelineId);

Build build = new Build()
{
    Definition = await definitionTask,
    Project = await projectTask
};

string parms1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(buildParameters);
string parms2 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(buildParameters);

if (buildParameters != null)
{
   //Add Parameters
}

if (sourceBuildId != null)
{
    return await buildClient.QueueBuildAsync(build, sourceBuildId: sourceBuildId);
}

return await buildClient.QueueBuildAsync(build);
```

In case it matters, this is in an older software that is running on .Net framework 4